# Cannot send mail over SMTP from server but I can from localhost

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, smtp, jakarta-mail

I get the following when I try to send an email over SMTP in my Java application. I'm running a Springboot app from a fat JAR on my Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 09 22:16:57 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: internetsmtp.test.com, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException: internetsmtp.test.com. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: internetsmtp.test.com, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException: internetsmtp.test.com
```

**Code:**

```
public void sendEmail(String from, String replyTo, String to, String subject, String body) {
        final Email email;
        try {
            email = DefaultEmail.builder()
                    .from(new InternetAddress(from))
                    .replyTo(new InternetAddress(replyTo))
                    .to(Lists.newArrayList(new InternetAddress(to)))
                    .subject(subject)
                    .body(body)
                    .encoding("UTF-8").build();
            emailService.send(email);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            log.error("MailUtil got exception while sending mail = " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**application.properties:**

```
# Server
server.port=8080

# Mail Config
spring.mail.host: internetsmtp.test.com
spring.mail.port: 25
spring.mail.username: user123
spring.mail.password: test123
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: false
spring.mail.persistence.enabled: false
spring.mail.persistence.redis.embedded: false
spring.mail.persistence.redis.enabled: false
spring.mail.scheduler.priorityLevels=10
```

I even tried **trusting the certificate**:

```
keytool -import -file "C:\mail.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre.1.8.0_121\lib\security\cacerts" -alias mail
```

I'm able to do all of this from **localhost** with no problem whatsoever. Is it possible that the issue is with my server blocking a connection to the SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception clearly states - `java.net.UnknownHostException: internetsmtp.test.com` . That means ( in this case) the DNS name is not resolvable by your application from the server . Make sure you are able to ping that domain from the server itself and that DNS access (port 53) is not blocked for that server

Comment: I allowed all ingoing/outgoing connections to port 53 to no avail. I also tried pinging the internetsmtp server and got the message ``Ping request could not find host. Please check the name and try again.`` Pinging ``google.com`` works, for example.

Comment: Great so that what/where is the DNS service/name server holding the "test.com" domain ??? Hint - there isn't any because this is a bogus name you entered locally on your machine (check the /etc/hosts file) or it was part of a private/internal DNS set up in your internal network. It's not connected/related to the real world.

Just give a valid DNS server address

Comment: That name in particular is part of an internal network. I didn't think it would be relevant to post it since nobody can reach it. I was just wondering what the protocol would be to open a connection between networks. I can ping to it from my local machine, but not from a particular server that I want access to it from.

Comment: if it's part of an internal network  then it's a network communication issue you need to resolve, either by yourself or with your IT administrator. It's not a code issue in any way. try and use ```dig``` command instead of ```ping``` for DNS resolution tests

Comment: I wonder if it is blocked automatically if tls is not enabled... Anyway I marked your answer as the solution since it identified the issue. I think my own solution is too specific to be of general use to require further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's a firewall blocking direct connections.  The JavaMail FAQ has more [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).